# How sed can be used to replace multiple patterns within a string for different patterns

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to replace multiple numbers in a line for different values. For example, in the string `"uncertainty = {  0.01 , 0.01 }"` it should substitute for `string "uncertainty = {  0.2 , 0.2 }"`

The problem is that these lines appear in hundreds of files with different quantities of numbers inside the brackets.

It could be:

```
"uncertainty = {  0.1 , 0.1, 0.1 }"
```

for

```
"uncertainty = {  0.3 , 0.3, 0.3 }"
```

---

or

```
"uncertainty = {  0.1 , 0.1, 0.1 , 0.1, 0.1, 0.1}"
```

for

```
"uncertainty = {  0.3 , 0.3, 0.3 , 0.3, 0.3, 0.3}
```

and so on, and I have to substitute all of them.

I could not see how sed could be used to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. Convert one item inside the curly brackets into a regular expression such as:

`[0-9]\.[0-9]1`

What this expression means is "a number, a period, a number, a one". If the format is consistent through-and-through, this will only replace instances of "0.01" when put through sed.[image: Terminal screenshot]

There are other tools that would meet these needs as well, such as `awk` and `tr`, but you would still use regular expressions for them as well. To replace numbers such as this in bulk, you could replace that "1" with another `[0-9]` or a `[1-3]` to specify numbers in the range of 1-3.

For more info on Regular Expressions see [Rexegg](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html). They greatly expand the usefulness of virtually all text manipulation utilities.

Answer (score 0):

I read about awk and it turned out to help half of my questions: to go through substrings of a string that matches a given string. Because awk have some limitations, I used sed
to clean up the mess, like this in which v1 and v2 are passed via a shell script that call this code

The awk part:

```
{
    found = match($0,"uncertainty")
    i = 4
    if (found) {
    while ( i < NF){
        if ($i = v1) {
          $i = v2
        }
        i = i + 2
    }
    print "        " $0 
    }
    else
    {
    print $0
    }
}
```

The shell part:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if directory already exists,

#!/bin/bash

# Check if directory already exists,

bitSizeDir="$1"
value1="$2"
value2="$3"

_mydir="$(pwd)"
find $bitSizeDir/ -type f  > Files;
while read line; do
    folder=`dirname "$line"`
    file=`basename "$line"`
    if [ "$file" = "input.c" ] ; then
    awk -v v1=$value1 -v v2=$value2 -f changeValues.awk $line > input.new
    mv input.new $folder
    cd $folder
    rm $file
    mv input.new input.c
    sed -i '' "s/$3 , \}/ \} /g" input.c
        cd $_mydir
    fi
done < Files
rm Files
```